# Number of Unique Sets

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving

There are three elements $a, b,$ and $c$.

How many sets are there of the form:

**1)** $\{\{x\}, \{y\}, \{x,y\}\}$, where $x, y \in \{a,b,c\}$

**2)** $\{\{x\}, \{x,y\}, \{x,z\}\}$, where $x, y, z \in \{a,b,c\}$

**3)** $\{\{x\}, \{y\}, \{x,y\}, \{x,z\}\}$, where $x, y, z \in \{a,b,c\}$

**Attempt:**

- I tried using combinations but was having a hard time.
- Say for the first example, there are three choices for $\{x\}$, then 2 choices for $\{y\}$, but since $x,y$ are now decided, is there a choice to make for $\{x,y\}$? Also since the order of these sets in the bigger set don't matter, how does this change things?
- Generating all the sets for this, I get that there are 3 distinct sets for the first example.

Comment: The first two have multiplicity $3$ & the third one has multiplicity $6$.

Comment: How did you do this?

Comment: You can describe (1) by the element which *wasn't* included in any of the entries.  You can describe (2) by the element which was used for the singleton entry.  You can describe (3) by the element which appeared in both of the two-element entries followed by the remaining singleton element.

Comment: That is, of course, assuming that you don't allow for $x,y,z$ to repeat.  If you *do* allow repetition, for example $x=y=a$ you could have $\{\{a\},\{a\},\{a,a\}\}$ which simplifies down to simply $\{\{a\}\}$ by removing redundancies.  This will increase the count for each.

Comment: @JMoravitz how exactly would you write this as a solution using $n$ choose $k$, which is where I'm confused?

Comment: I wouldn't.  There is no rule that a counting problem must have an answer involving permutations or combinations.